# Excel: Calculate a cell based on values below matching criteria from another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So, I have a list of letters and numbers, each letter has a number assigned to it. In a separate column, I have one instance of a letter - I'll refer to these rows as parent rows. Each parent row has an empty value in the number column. I'd like to be able to calculate the mode of the number values beneath the parent row of a given letter and populate the parent row number with that. (See Screenshot). I'd be doing this for multiple parent rows - I'd like to be able to filter the number row by blank values and fill the formula down. Is this even possible?

I've tried using =MODE(IF("LetterColumn"="Letter","Numbers")

[image: Example Spreadsheet]

Mode for "F" would be 10.
Mode for "G" Would be 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `OFFSET` function to avoid a circular reference.

Formula in `C2`: `=MODE(OFFSET(C2,1,0,COUNTIF(B:B,B2)-1,1))`

**Result:**

[image]

**Notes:**

- In order to work, values in `B` need to be in consecutive order.
- Heavy use of `OFFSET` formula can slow down your Excel

Let me know, if you need an explanation.

Comment: This works perfectly with SUMIF, but I need MODE.

Comment: @wheel58m: There you go!

Comment: What do you mean by B values need to be in consecutive order?

Comment: All of the same letters (e.g. "F") must appear one below the other without interruption, i.e. no other letter (e.g. "G") may come in between.

Comment: The reason for this restriction is caused be the `OFFSET` formula which can only provide a contiguous range of cells.

Answer (score 1):

`=MODE.MULT(C3:INDEX(C:C,MAX((B:B=A2)*(ROW(B:B)))))` not sure if this is what you mean, since you don't show the desired result, but this uses MODE(.MULT) over the range from the cell below untill the last cell where the letter equals.
This is provided that the range shows no gaps as in the example.
Like mentioned offset recalculates each time a cell is changed. INDEX doesn't, so it's only recalculating if a range is changed effecting the formula, unlike OFFSET.
[image]

Comment: Interesting solution that avoids using `OFFSET` :-). In order to avoid a "Spill over" error, you should add the "@"-sign before `MODE.MULT`.

Comment: Can you explain why adding `@` would improve the formula?

Comment: The cells below the formula are already blocked by the values. The formula will try to spill over, if it finds multiple valid results, which is the case if two (or more) values occur equally often. As it cannot spill over, it will show an "error". The "@" will tell the formula to provide one result only!!

Comment: Or you wrap the formula in `TRANSPOSE` to let the spill over take place in the adjacent columns. This way, the user would see, that multiple values occur equally often.

Comment: There's no spill. It just calculates the most occuring and shows it.

Comment: I had a spill when TWO or MORE result occur equally often, e.g. 4 times 10 & 4 times 12.

Comment: Ok, but the opening post doesn't clarify if it occurs and how to deal with it. Spilling in transpose is a workaround, but we simply don't know what is the intention.